# Why do I get Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments while creating new instance with private constructor using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at beans.ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:14)
```

i am trying to invoke private constructor with `newInstance()` method using reflection. Here is the code.

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    
    private Test() {
        System.out.println("private constructor.. Test");
    }

    public Test(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Test(String name, int id) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Test(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class ClientTest {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            Class cl = Class.forName("beans.Test");
            Constructor[] c =  cl.getDeclaredConstructors();
            c[0].setAccessible(true);
            c[0].newInstance();
            
            for(Constructor cnt : c) {
                System.out.println(cnt);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the constructor at index 0 is the the private no-args constructor?

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to the docs for [`getDeclaredConstructors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--).

Here it says (emphasis mine)

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are **not in any particular order**

It is safer to use the method for getting a specific constructor `getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)`. That way you can specify exactly which constructor you want.

Since this method takes a vararg as argument, to get the no-arg constructor you can simply call `cl.getDeclaredConstructor()`.